# How to declare the nested classes correctly?

Tags: c++

Following code is a implemention of Binary Tree, coming from a C++ data structure text.
I canot compile the code successfully, getting some error messages. Mainly, the error lines comes from the last two of the code. How to fix this problem?
My IDE is CODE::BLOCK 12.11.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

typedef int Elem;
struct Node
{
Elem elt;
Node *par;
Node *left;
Node *right;
Node():elt(),par(NULL),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
};

class Position
{
private:
Node *v;
public:
Position(Node *_v=NULL):v(_v){}
Elem &operator*(){return v->elt;}
Position left()const{return Position(v->left);}
Position right()const{return Position(v->right);}
Position parent()const{return Position(v->par);}
bool isRoot()const{return v->par==NULL;}
bool isExternal()const{return v->left==NULL&&v->right==NULL;}
friend class LinkedBinaryTree;
};
typedef std::list<Position> PositionList;

class LinkedBinaryTree
{
protected:
struct Node; //This line is by me, the text merely tell you "insert Node declaration here. . ."  I don't know whether this line is correct or not.
public:
class Position; // Also by me, the text merely tell you "insert Position declaration here. . ." I don't know wwhether this line is correct or not.
public:
LinkedBinaryTree();
int size()const;
bool empty()const;
Position root()const;
PositionList positions()const;
void addRoot();
void expandeExternal(const Position& p);
protected:
void preorder(Node* v,PositionList& pl)const;
private:
Node* _root;
int n;
};


LinkedBinaryTree::LinkedBinaryTree():_root(NULL),n(0){}
int LinkedBinaryTree::size()const{return n;}
bool LinkedBinaryTree::empty()const{return size()==0;}
LinkedBinaryTree::Position LinkedBinaryTree::root()const{Position(_root);} //canot compile successfully, this error messages is : C:\Users\user\Documents\aa\main.cpp|58|error: return type 'class LinkedBinaryTree::Position' is incomplete
void LinkedBinaryTree::addRoot(){_root=new Node;n=1;} //canoot compile successfully, this error message is C:\Users\user\Documents\aa\main.cpp|59|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct LinkedBinaryTree::Node'
```

There are many error messages, I select one of them to represent the error messages.

Comment: read the error messages, fix the compile errors....

Comment: Reduce the number of lines in your program until you have the smallest set that produces the problem. Very likely the problem will stare you in the face at that time.

Comment: Code::blocks is an IDE not a compiler.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I do read the error messages, but I can't fix the error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
class LinkedBinaryTree {
protected:
 struct Node;
```

is called a forward declaration (of `Node`). It tells the compiler there is a type with that *name*, but it is not a definition of a class. You cannot create an instance of a type, unless its definition is visible. A forward declaration is not a definition.

If you had written:

```
class LinkedBinaryTree {
protected:
 struct Node { /* ... */ };
```

Then you would be able to create a `Node`.

The forward declaration of a nested class is generally useful when you have codependent types, or you prefer to order declarations in a specific way.

The forward declaration is useful to tell the compiler there is a type with that name, so it can understand your intent before it is used:

```
class LinkedBinaryTree {
protected:
 struct Node;
 void foo(Node*);
 struct Node { /* ... */ };
```

In this case, a pointer does not require physical dependence, so the name is enough to satisfy the compiler when it sees the declaration of `foo`.

Also note that your forward declaration declares a `Node` and `Position` in the class' scope, so the compiler takes it to mean that `void preorder(Node* v,PositionList& pl)const;` uses the types local to the class; e.g. `void LinkedBinaryTree::preorder(LinkedBinaryTree::Node* v, LinkedBinaryTree::PositionList& pl)const;`, rather than the `Position` and `Node` declared in the global namespace in your code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Nested declaration should normally happen inside the class, like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

class LinkedBinaryTree
{
  protected:
  typedef int Elem;
  struct Node
  {
     Elem elt;
     Node *par;
     Node *left;
     Node *right;
     Node():elt(),par(NULL),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
  };

  public:
  class Position
  {
    private:
    Node *v;
    public:
    Position(Node *_v=NULL):v(_v){}
    Elem &operator*(){return v->elt;}
    Position left()const{return Position(v->left);}
    Position right()const{return Position(v->right);}
    Position parent()const{return Position(v->par);}
    bool isRoot()const{return v->par==NULL;}
    bool isExternal()const{return v->left==NULL&&v->right==NULL;}
    friend class LinkedBinaryTree;
  };
  typedef std::list<Position> PositionList;
  public:
  LinkedBinaryTree();
  int size()const;
  bool empty()const;
  Position root()const;
  PositionList positions()const;
  void addRoot();
  void expandeExternal(const Position& p);
  protected:
  void preorder(Node* v,PositionList& pl)const;
  private:
  Node* _root;
  int n;
};


LinkedBinaryTree::LinkedBinaryTree():_root(NULL),n(0){}
int LinkedBinaryTree::size()const{return n;}
bool LinkedBinaryTree::empty()const{return size()==0;}
LinkedBinaryTree::Position LinkedBinaryTree::root()const{Position(_root);} //canot compile successfully, this error messages is : C:\Users\user\Documents\aa\main.cpp|58|error: return type 'class LinkedBinaryTree::Position' is incomplete
void LinkedBinaryTree::addRoot(){_root=new Node;n=1;}
```

Comment: This declaration works. Thank you. Why can't I declare and define them outside class?

Comment: The whole point of nested classes are that they happen within another class. Therefor it does not make sense to define them outside the mother class.